# template equivalent of BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

[BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) provides a means of creating new types out of old ones - like typedef, but it actually provides a new typedef which the compiler can recognize for overloading functions, etc.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF supports templates:

```
template <class element>
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(vector<element>, List<element>);
```

does not compile. Is there any way to make this work, or a somewhat light weight workaround?

(Of course, I should point out typedef doesn't support templates either, but in C++11 you can use [alias declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to accomplish the same thing).

Comment: Taking [the source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp) and doing some light editing should be straightforward. The bigger problem is that the design works best with primitive types, and doesn't work well with member functions and some overloaded operators.

Comment: @Praetorian, did you find a solution if I may ask?

Comment: @aickley I only edited the question, Justin asked it :) If you really need this, my suggestion would be the same as TC's in the comment above ... make your own starting from the Boost version. But, as he points out too, you may find the results less than satisfactory.